# Как правильно удалить дубликаты слов в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана строка [question](https://stepik.org/lesson/814369/step/5?unit=817681) "Python is best I love python" нужно вывести строку без дуплей соответственно без последнего слова но у меня где то теряется "Ай"

```
x,n = input().split(),[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i].lower() not in str(n).lower():
        n.append(x[i])
print(*n)
```

и на выходе получаю "Python is best love".

Answer (score 1):

Лучше завести множество с использованными словами, с помощью которого проверять повторы.

```
x,n = input().split(),[]
used = set()
for s in x:
    if s.lower() not in used:
        n.append(s)
        used.add(s.lower())
print(*n)
```

```
Python is best I love python
Python is best I love
```

Пояснения о пропаже `I`.
У вас `I` пропала, потому что вы ищете совпадения в строковом представлении всего списка, а не в отдельных элементов списка.
Если распечатать на каждой итерации `str(n)`, то выведутся строки

```
['Python']
['Python', 'is'] # в этой строке есть i
['Python', 'is', 'best'] # в этой строке есть i
['Python', 'is', 'best'] # в этой строке есть i
['Python', 'is', 'best', 'love']
```

Поэтому результат проверки `if x[i].lower() not in str(n).lower():` или, конкретно, `if 'i' not in "['Python', 'is', 'best']":` будет ложным и `I` не добавится в список.